# I am getting the following error when I am trying to import an existing android studio project.Is there any solution for this?

Tags: android

The error is "The patch c:\android-sdk-windows does not belong to a directory.Android studio will use this Andriod SDK instead C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' and will modify the project's local.properties file.

[I am getting the following error when I am trying to import an android sdk project in Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp9Yk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any problems. Just press ok and then set correct path of Android SDK if needed.